# Xcode images appearing very small

Tags: ios, xcode, svg

I'm converting an Android project to iOS and because it doesn't support SVG I had to convert icons to png using this tool https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-png (i used others too).

But I'm having a weird problem, or maybe I don't understand how images work in iOS, but no matter the resolution I give them they appear the same size in Xcode (very small) until I reach a huge one 1920x1920px which loads very big as it should.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/giYhwKn.png]

I don't get why from 24px to 960px it looks the same, I would expect that it looks small but at least different in size. Then at 1920, it looks gigantic. I also tried different DPI.
I think it would be weird to provide such images, even if they are only 16kb.

What is happening here?

EDIT:

Here are the files i'm using

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYfp6IbCXk9LgN_K-ho_bBnj_-Iv_mj4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Use pdf format for images and change your imageView's contentMode to aspectFit or scaleToFill. Content mode depends your image's attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is bug of interface builder. Image bellow is different of interface builder and run.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, how embarassing. I was so fixated on how it looked that i never ran it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change the image to 1X it will be large . 
in assets in this part : 
[image]

Comment: I did try that 2x and 3x, but to no avail.
https://i.imgur.com/89xhpuA.png

Comment: no , please clear them and just keep one filed and change the position to 1x in that

Comment: At 1x is where images are when they are added first, the first thing i tried. I changed to 2x and 3x when that didn't work to see if it changed something. I think i'm missing some configuration.